# ios inocming call not workin but android working flutter_callkit_incoming: ^2.0.1+1 why

Tags: flutter

We are using flutter_callkit_incoming for our call processing but after implementation when incoming calling in iphone then application crashed

I am getting following error when I use "AppIcon" as Icon name in iOS Params. AppIcon folder contains all the app icons
I get same error when I create CallKitIcon folder as given in their example and then I still get the same error

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the crash. It would also be helpful to include the relevant code snippets. (e.g. what your file structure looks like, if it crashes on a line of code in your project then what the code snippet is where it crashes, etc.)

Comment: ok  i will hare my code